How do you use plotly express to make a scatterplot when you have multiindex columns?
I am looking to plot a scatterplot given 4 columns, all in the format of tuple pairs, which will access a multiindex dataframe. This is the shortened form of the code, to spare several pages of code, but I have tried flattening the columns to strings to no avail.
Here is the data snippet:
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ("Q", "stuff"),
    ("R", "mostuff"),
    ("S", "othstuff"),
    ("T", "finalstuff"),
])

# Generate random data for the DataFrame
data = {
    ("Q", "stuff"): np.random.rand(100),
    ("R", "mostuff"): np.random.rand(100),
    ("S", "othstuff"): np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 100),
    ("T", "finalstuff"): np.random.rand(100) * 100,  # Ensure numeric data
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

This is then put in to a class and used in a panel, but the short form of the code is printed here. It assumes these are input as variables.
def create_scatter(self, tupz=lambda _ls: tuple(map(str, _ls))):
    _df = self.df.copy()
    _df.columns = tupz(_df.columns.to_list())
    _x, _y, _cl, _sz = tupz([self.x, self.y, self.color_col, self.size_col])
    
    _df_sparse = _df.loc[:, [_x, _y, _cl, _sz]].dropna()
    
    fig = px.scatter(
        _df_sparse,
        x=_x, 
        y=_y, 
        color=_cl, 
        size=_sz, 
    )

The error I continually get looks something like this, which I assume has to do with sending in a tuple.
    sizeref = args["data_frame"][args["size"]].max() / args["size_max"] ** 2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

The tuple assumption is due mostly to another error that comes up that says:
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of hover_data key `index` is 5150, whereas the length of previously-processed arguments ['x', 'y', 'size'] is 2

